# PPT VBA -> from hyperlink to table

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

Crosspost from Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/12t1lgf/ppt_vba_from_hyperlink_to_table/

I'm trying to figure out if this can work: finding in which table a hyperlink is on a slide. The first loop I have is looping through all hyperlinks on a slide and finding the right one (simplified here):

```
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
For Each h In sld.Hyperlinks
    If h.TextToDisplay = "2021" Then
        'h = hyperlink
        Set k1 = h.Parent 'k1=actionsetting
        Set k2 = k1.Parent 'k2=textrange
        Set k3 = k2.Parent 'k3=textframe
        Set k4 = k3.Parent 'k4=shape = inside of cell
    End If
Next
```

So to find my table on this slide, this works:

```
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTable Then
        Set t = shp.Table
        Exit For
    End If
Next shp
'Assume t has been found, loop though it and search for text "2021", which is the hyperlink I'm looking for.
For rw = 1 To t.Rows.Count
    For col = 1 To t.Columns.Count
        Set c = t.Cell(rw, col)
        If c.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2021" Then
            Set sh4 = c.Shape
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col
Next rw
```

When I run these 2 blocks, both Shapes - sh4 from the second loop and k4 from the first loop are exactly the same shape. However, that's quite some looping I need to do whenever I have a hyperlink. What I'm basically looking for is to go "up" from k4 to find the cell (and table) it is in... The .parent of k4 is the Slide, so that doesn't get me anywhere and the only other properties of that shape I can see are Top/Left/Width/Height :-(...

Anyone here with a better suggestion how to get from the hyperlink to the cell it is in?

Comment: This is sort of a bug in PowerPoint; the .Parent property of cells doesn't behave as you'd expect it to. Off top of head, you might have to loop through the hyperlinks collection, then for each hyperlink, loop through the shapes on the slide (and each cell of tables) to test whether the shape's textrange has a hyperlink.

Comment: how about searching for the hyperlink in the xml directly?

Comment: If you go "up" from the hyperlink object to the parent `Shape`, you can loop the table cells on the slide and check for `cel.Shape Is hyperlinkParentShape`

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks, that confirms my suspicion :-(.

Comment: Reported it as an issue with MSFT, see if they get back to me :-). https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/discussions/1693

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim sld As Slide, h As Hyperlink, tbl As Table
    
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    
    For Each h In sld.Hyperlinks
        Set tbl = ParentTable(sld, h)
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Found parent table for " & h.Address
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Function ParentTable(sld As Slide, hl As Hyperlink) As Table
    Dim shp As Shape, r As Long, c As Long, hlShape As Shape, tbl As Table
    Set hlShape = ParentOfType(hl, "Shape")
    If hlShape Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTable Then
            Set tbl = shp.Table
            For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count    'loop all cells
            For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
                If tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape Is hlShape Then 'same Shape object?
                    Set ParentTable = tbl
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next c
            Next r
        End If
    Next shp
End Function

Function ParentOfType(obj As Object, pType As String) As Object
    Dim p As Object
    Set p = obj.Parent
    Do While TypeName(p) <> pType
        Set p = p.Parent
        If TypeName(p) = "Application" Then Exit Function 'at top...
    Loop
    Set ParentOfType = p
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of what I had gotten to... The comment of Steve Rinsberg above kind of confirms my suspicion: the only way is a double loop, there is no property to go "up" from a hyperlink.